# This MySqlConnection is already in use

Tags: c#, aspnetboilerplate

I created an RecurringJob with Hangfire, but when the job is finish I'm getting the following ERROR:

```
ERROR 2018-12-05 15:20:05,982 [fc937] Hangfire.AutomaticRetryAttribute - Failed to process the job '81': an exception occurred.
System.InvalidOperationException: This MySqlConnection is already in use.   See https://fl.vu/mysql-conn-reuse
at MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.StartQuerying(MySqlCommand command) in    C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\ServerSession.cs:line 149
at MySqlConnector.Core.TextCommandExecutor.ExecuteReaderAsync(String commandText, MySqlParameterCollection parameterCollection, CommandBehavior  behavior, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\TextCommandExecutor.cs:line 33
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlCommand.cs:line 261
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlTransaction.CommitAsync(IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlTransaction.cs:line 25
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlTransaction.Commit() in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlTransaction.cs:line 12
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalTransaction.Commit()
at Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Uow.DbContextEfCoreTransactionStrategy.Commit() in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp.EntityFrameworkCore\EntityFrameworkCore\Uow\DbContextEfCoreTransactionStrategy.cs:line 66
at Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Uow.EfCoreUnitOfWork.CommitTransaction() in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp.EntityFrameworkCore\EntityFrameworkCore\Uow\EfCoreUnitOfWork.cs:line 92
at Abp.Domain.Uow.UnitOfWorkBase.Complete() in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp\Domain\Uow\UnitOfWorkBase.cs:line 256
at Abp.Domain.Uow.UnitOfWorkInterceptor.PerformSyncUow(IInvocation invocation, UnitOfWorkOptions options) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp\Domain\Uow\UnitOfWorkInterceptor.cs:line 68
at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
```

the code like this:

```
public class TestJob : ITransientDependency
{
    private readonly IDapperRepository<Customer> _customerDapperRepository;
    private readonly IRepository<Customer> _customerRepository;
    private readonly IRepository<User, long> _userRepository;
    public TestJob(...)
    {
     ...
    }
    [UnitOfWork]
    [AutomaticRetry(Attempts = 0)]
    public virtual void ExecuteJob()
    {
       var someCustomerList = GetSomeCustomerList();
       foreach (var customer in someCustomerList )
       {
          //do some db operations
       }
    }
    private List<Customer> GetSomeCustomerList()
    {
       //get some Customer with conditions
    }
}
```

The code above does not report an error during debugging,I'm confused what's wrong.

Comment: Hey there, have this been solved?

Comment: In my my case, I forgot an `await` of `Task`s inside a loop, so those `Task`s didn't complete before the `.SaveChangesAsync()`.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Entity Framework and creating a new query using a property from a list of items that has not been resolved yet, then you can get this error.

What fixed it for me was simply adding `.ToList()` before using the property :)

In your case it would be:

````
var someCustomerList = GetSomeCustomerList().ToList() //adding ToList will resolve it;
       foreach (var customer in someCustomerList )
       {
          //do some db operations
       }```
````

Comment: Note that this evaluates the SQL (executes it) upfront. This can have performance issues in some cases

Comment: yes, this is amazing, I just occur this issue on Blazor with repo pattern, same error when using dbcontext with Join() method, finally add ToList() and success, had read about ToList() is help to dispose the dbcontext.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using asynchronous programming as was my case, make sure that in your flow you are not doing a round trip to DB using async Task and a new asynchronous round trip to DB without use Task, when I noticed and I changed my code, it was fixed

Answer (score 0):

Although i'm not entirely sure of what's happening, consider doing the following:

- Closing the connection each time you use it;
- Consider doing all of your database operations inside a [using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) scope. This way, each time you query your database, the connection instance is properly disposed, without you having to bother about closing it.

Answer (score 0):

Im my case I just changed *AddScoped* to *AddTransient*

e.g

```
services.AddScoped<DbSession>();
```

To

```
services.AddTransient<DbSession>();
```